# Modification of Janus nanoparticles

Tags: chemical-biology, nanotechnology

I would like to synthesis gold/polyacrylic acid (PAA) Janus nanoparticles in solution.
Any ideas how I can functionalize gold with a photosensitizer and PAA with an antibody so that there would be no other unwanted interactions?